# Newly created wallet does not exist on blok.io EOS explorer

Tags: nodeos, mainnet

I have followed the blow quick start to run EOS node on my mac
[enter link description here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs)
And I have created a wallet using wallet api  http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/wallet/create by account name thomsonimjd3.

When I checked the account name on Explorer https://bloks.io/, it syas Account Not Found.

Where am I going wrong?  or the node that I have run in my local which will not syncronize to main blockchain network, is it like private network on my local? if so How can I run EOS node which is connected to main blockchain network?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because you have created account on private local node and you are trying to get account from main live node that's why you are not getting your account on main node's explorer. **Mainnet node and Private node** both are different thing.

If you have selected mainnet from the drop down menu in https://bloks.io/ you will get **mainnet** transactions only and if you have selected **jungle(testnet)** or any other then you will get transaction as per your selection.

**To built testnet node** 
Follow this https://github.com/EOS-Jungle-Testnet/Node-Installation

And if you want to **run mainnet node** go for this https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet